# Main fuse blows, individual fuses do not

Tags: repair, circuit-breaker

Recently I moved into a 4 year old house. The house has two 40 amp board on separate systems. One of the system's main fuse switch has been blowing recently as a high power tool is inserted into any outlet. The tool turns on for 1 second and dies when the main, not the individual, fuse is triggered. This is odd as that this just happened recently, and any recent electrical changes were undone to trace the failure to no success.

Comment: How powerful is the tool? Maybe it is broken at all? Also some other appliances can affect the overall power draw.

Comment: What is the tool. Sounds like inrush current and the tool itself is taking longer to start, probably because it has worn / become dirty. You probably should not be plugging it into a 40A breaker/fuse.

Comment: This appears to be a statement not a question. In any case it would suit the DIY not electronics Stack.

Comment: Two high powered devices, a bohrdrill and a vacuum. I shouls have mentioned that. I am thinking it is likely the fuse box itself, but it handled both devices  alone before as well. They are never operating at the same time.

Comment: What kind of almost-brand-new house still has fuses???? Or do you mean the main GFCI (RCD in UK) triggers but not the circuit's own breaker? If so, that tells you right there, to suspect a ground fault with the tool. Get it checked for live -> ground insulation breakdown.

Comment: Also take a look at the power meter before powering the tool..

Comment: "and any recent electrical changes were undone " hmmmm....

Comment: Lighting. We uninstalled all the lighting.

Comment: As @BrianDrummond suggests I'd also suspect a ground fault. If you were running extra wiring around for lighting you may have a neutral-ground short in there somewhere.

Comment: No extra wiring. I wonder if the wiring above the ceiling might have been knicked by the bohrdrill while the lighting fixtures were installed. I don't know if that is able to lead to a ground fault. But what I read is that the installation deterioration might be the cause, in this case a drill bit hitting the wiring.

Answer (score 3):

In places where people say "knicked by the bohrdrill", it's common practice to use whole-house ground fault detectors (they say residual current devices) in the main panel (they say fuse box).

The two 40A boards is not weird in 230V land.  They bring 3-phase ~400V power down the block, 230V to neutral.  Having two boards means he is getting 2 phases.

In American style per-circuit GFCIs, it matters a lot when you cross up neutrals between circuits.  A whole-house GFCI/RCD won't care about neutral mixing *among circuits out of that panel*. ** But *two* whole-house GFCIs will care a great deal if circuits from the two panels have *their* neutrals crossed.  That is also super bad because of the 400V potential between the two hots.

I gather this recent work has to do with adding the second panel and moving any circuits over to it?   That will expose any crossed neutral problems.

Of course, crossing any hot to any ground, or any neutral to any ground, will also trip RCDs.

Sometimes the problem is only provoked when current flows, e.g. Neutral-Ground crosses.   In that case some current is going down the wrong wire.  With no load, half of 0 is 0 and that won't trip an RCD.

---

** Note that neutral mixing is still bad, since neutrals don't have fuses and rely on the overcurrent protection from their partner hot.